Problem with \bottomrule when using booktabs and \csvreader together, missplaced \noalign Latex
I am trying to implement this table into a bigger document but I am unable to do so. If I don't use \bottomrule then it works fine but when I try to add that line it gives the error "misplaced \noalign".
.tex File:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{Substituent (R)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{P} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{As} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
& C1 & C2 & C3 & C4 \\
\midrule
\csvreader{var.csv}{}{
  \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcolii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv\\}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example table with bottom rule using csvsimple}
\end{table}

\end{document}

var.csv:
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,0,2
5,6,7,6,7

I tried to insert \before bottomrule but then it leaves a large space before the line. Also if I don't use csvreader and I simply type out the table then it's fine, the line appears as is supposed to. But this is not really efficient because I have to create multiple tables with lots of rows so it would be really time consuming to type them out. Thank you in advance.

You can use the late after line=\\ option to start new tabular lines when you read the csv file:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{var.csv}
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,0,2
5,6,7,6,7
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{Substituent (R)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{P} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{As} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
& C1 & C2 & C3 & C4 \\
\midrule
\csvreader[late after line=\\]{var.csv}{}{
  \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcolii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example table with bottom rule using csvsimple}
\end{table}

\end{document}

